# Cannot input number in multi-dimensional array pointer to pointer

Tags: c, xcode

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int **arr;
    arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if(i == 0 || j == 0)
                arr[i][j] = 1;
            else
                arr[i][j] = arr[i - 1][j] + arr[i][j - 1];
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
    free(arr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code makes a 2-dimensional array with a pointer; I want assign value `arr[i][j] = 1`. However, an error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` occurs in XCode on a Mac. I don't know how to solve the problem. What is my mistake?  The assigning for loop is where the trouble occurs.

Comment: @user3121023 better `sizeof(*arr)`

Comment: Thank you.. i understand my mistake.....thankyou